# Caching of external XML file, what should be done?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I got a maintainance project in wordpress and I need to parse external xml. Previous developer has already implemented this. I just wanted to know whether it is a good way or I need to use my own.

He is caching the xml in a json file which cached for 5 min. He asked me to call it using ajax and then parse it.

Do you think this is a good way ? can't we directly parse the xml files rather than caching and parsing  ?

he is using external api_cache for getting the xml and caching in a json file

**PHP FILE**

```
 require 'api_cache/api_cache.php';
 $cache_file = 'jsonfile';
 $api_call ='xmlfile';
 $cache_for = 5; 
 $api_cache = new API_cache ($api_call, $cache_for, $cache_file);

  if (!$res = $api_cache->get_api_cache()) {
      $res = "{error: 'Could not load cache'}";
  }
 ob_start();
 echo $res;
 $json_body = ob_get_clean();

 header('Content-Type: application/json');
 header('Content-length: '.strlen($json_body));
 header('Expires: '.$api_cache->get_expires_datetime());
 echo $json_body;
```

Comment: I see the code for the cache retrieval, but not the code where the cache is generated, could you post the relevant method for API_cache that shows how the file is retrieved and cached?

Comment: Yes, I can post the same. but this is a library file for making a cache json file from http://www.profilepicture.co.uk/caching-api-responses-php/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of the cache is to prevent the (resource expensive) code from running multiple times if it is requested multiple times.

Instead, you save a copy of (or **cache**) the file, and serve it instead when a multitude of requests arrives in a short period of time. Example workflow:

1. User A requests file.
2. System checks if cache file exists.
3. Cache file doesn't exist. Create one, keep for 5 minutes. (resource expensive)
4. Serve cached file.
5. 3 minutes later, User B requests file.
6. System checks if cache file exists.
7. Cache file exists.
8. Serve cached file. (saved a lot of resources).
9. 3 minutes later, User C requests file.
10. System checks if cache file exists.
11. Cache file expired, Create it again, keep for 5 minutes
12. etc.

It's an effective method on high traffic sites, or in applications where data is unlikely to change, but to check it is highly resource expensive.

Comment: Thank you very much for replying here Truth. As you know this php file is creating json file so should I need to hit json file for getting response ?? but we get the json file only after hitting the php file who generates the json.

Comment: You should hit the PHP file. The PHP file will determine if the cache exists or expired and provide a cached/new version of the json file. Don't query the json file directly or you may get unexpected results (in case PHP deletes the cache file).